# Eclipse - can't load 4.3 or higher android emu

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

I installed the ADT bundle from google and have updated eclipse as well as went through the SDK updates and made sure that all of the tools and ARM EABI files have been installed for 4.0 and above. When I try running an emulator with 4.1.2 everything works fine. But when I try 4.3 or 4.4 the VD starts up and just keeps loading with the "android" text for an hour+. 
Here are my settings for the 4.3 virtual device: http://puu.sh/9ZJIM/9011ebf56e.png

I've played around with the settings but still no luck. And I have a decent computer to run the emu. I have an i5 and 8 gb of ram as well as a dedicated graphics card

I am also getting these errors in the logcat of the ddms while trying to load the emulator if it helps http://puu.sh/9ZLjF/32c95efb1d.png

Comment: Do you get any error in loading VD?

Comment: I don't get a popup window or anything but I edited the OP to show the errors I get in the logcat

Comment: When you start your AVD from AVD manager it must show some error or messages like https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2895/14587956341_106faa3da1_o.png

Comment: just this http://puu.sh/9ZMAd/5018102e3e.jpg  If you mean the logcat in the java perspective then there are a lot of errors rushing down the screen: http://puu.sh/9ZMGZ/9809be5905.png